# json stringify to php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to pass the key values into php page.

At php page, I will start to read value by matching `ajaxcallid`.

But it not working.

It gotta do with syntax/way I am passing in causing error.

```
parse error
invalid json: ajax call id is missing
```

JavaScript/AJAX:

```
var person = { 
     "Address"    :   "123 Anywhere St.", 
     "City"       :   "Springfield", 
     "PostalCode" :   99999
};

alert(person);          

person= JSON.stringify(person);

alert(person);

$.ajax({
    url: 'ROOT_URL/admin/ajaxtest.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {ajaxcallid: '26', jsarr: person},
    timeout: 5000,
    success:  function(output) {
        alert(output.Address);
    },
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxcallid']))
{    
    if($_REQUEST['ajaxcallid']==26)
    {    
        //example, I want to read value of person.Address, person.City, 
        //person.PostalCode
    //what is the easiest way
        $phparr= json_decode($_REQUEST['jsarr']);
        //do all other operation
        $output= json_encode($phparr);
    }
}
else
{
    $output= "ajax call id is missing";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Please dump your `$phparr` just before encoding as JSON and paste the output.

Answer (score 32):

If you are not using dataType : 'json', you might need to do stripslashes

```
$.post(window.data.baseUrl, {posts : JSON.stringify(posts)});
```

And in php:

```
$posts = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['posts']));
```

Answer (score 7):

This helped me:

```
 data = json_decode($this->request->data['jsarr'], true);
```

in your php code for accessing the record

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a guess and say that you SHOULDN'T stringify anything.  I believe JQuery will do that for you.  Namely, no person = JSON.stringify(person).  Give that a try.

Comment: absolutely agree. why would you encapsulate the stringified parameters in an object and then send them through ajax, when jquery passes an OBJECT of parameters.

Comment: max_input_vars in PHP 5.3.9. limits input vars to 1000 if you have huge json file then it can give you PHP warning.

Answer (score 3):

This is what your `$.ajax` call and the `PHP` side should look like:

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/ajaxtest.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        ajaxcallid: "26",
        person: JSON.stringify({
            "Address" : "123 Anywhere St.",
            "City" : "Springfield",
            "PostalCode" : "99999"
        })
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    if (!data) {
        // generic error message here
    } else if (data == 'invalid') {
        alert('no ajaxcallid received');
    } else {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data); // if you pass back the object
        alert(result.Address);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxcallid'])) {
    if ((int) $_REQUEST['ajaxcallid'] == 26) {
        $personData = json_decode($_REQUEST['person']);
        $address = $personData->Address;
        $postalCode = $personData->PostalCode;
        $returnData = json_encode($personData);
        echo $personData;
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo 'invalid';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data_array = json_decode($json_string);
```

If you want objects to be converted into associative arrays, then add true into function:

```
$data_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with `PHP` but from my experience with `ASP.net` following may help you.

Add `contentType` key to ajax settigns:

```
type: "POST",
contentType:'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
```

also I think you need to `stringify` whole value you are assigning to `data` like this:

```
var person = { 
     "Address"    :   "123 Anywhere St.", 
     "City"       :   "Springfield", 
     "PostalCode" :   99999
};

var d= {ajaxcallid: '26', jsarr: person};
var dat=JSON.stringify(d);


......
data: dat,
......
```